# Passing data to a viewModel from viewModel in Android with Jetpack Compose and Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am building an Android app using Jetpack Compose and Hilt, trying to follow the MVVM pattern.
I have 2 composable functions:

```
@Composable
fun TimerView(
    viewModel: TimerViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {...}
```

and

```
@Composable
fun SensorScreen(viewModel: SensorViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val values = viewModel.recentValues.mapValues { it.value.collectAsState(listOf(0f)) }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
            TimerView()
...}
```

As you can see the first one is embedded in the first one, each of them have their own View Models, the TimerViewModel is as follows:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TimerViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {
    val totalTime = 100
    private val _time = MutableStateFlow(totalTime)
    val time = _time.asStateFlow()
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (true) {
                delay(1000)
                _time.value = Integer.max(0, _time.value - 1)
                if (_time.value == 0) {
                    onTimeFinished()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to pass the totalTime value from the parent ViewModel - `SensorViewModel`, how should I do that to follow best practises and MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The first question that I'd like to ask is why are you using two ViewModels? Is it because of some necessity that you've thought about or is it just because you have two nested composables?

If the reasoning is the seconds one, I would argue that you could just use one ViewModel and pass down in the composition tree only the required properties and functions to the composable that require'em, so that you abide to the best practice of State Hoisting.

Generally we'd like to:

1. Interact with the UI
2. By such interaction trigger some action in the viewModel
3. If necessary update the state of the UI in the viewModel
4. Reflect the UI state changes in the UI

I generally don't see a recommendation in which you should let your viewModels communicate and I would avoid it if I don't have a clear picture of what I'm doing.

In the case that you have one ViewModel, you can just pass to your TimerView the required variable `totalTime` and you could do so deferring its read as much as possibile, to avoid useless recompositions.

I'll leave a few nice pages from Android Developer that should help have a clearer picture!
I hope this helped, otherwise, let me know what I could do to fix it!

**Resources**

[Unidirectional Data Flow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf)

[Some ViewModels Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/recommendations?hl=en#viewmodel)

[Defer reads as long as possible](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive reply. The main reason I want 2 view models is that the TimerView composable will be reusable in many other composable functions and I don't want to duplicate the logic for the timer, how would you suggest doing that in this case?

Comment: You should pass in `TimerView` by arguments only necessary data. Look at `TimerView` you pass `viewModel` but you don't need the whole `viewModel` you just need some data exposed by `viewModel`. So you need grab that data before creating `TimerView` and pass it in there in arguments: `fun TimerView(dataFromViewModel: Any)` and then use this `dataFromViewModel` instead of the whole `viewModel`